# to be out even ten paces

Tags: meaning

> 'The old man shook his head cunningly. "Na--Na--Na!" he cried. "I know
>   better. Every time I tell my tale men stone me. But, Thanes, I will
>   tell you a greater thing. Listen!" He told us how many paces it was
>   from some Saxon Saint's shrine to another shrine, and how many more
>   back to the Abbey of the Battle.
>
> '"Ay," said he. "**I have trodden it too often to be out even ten
>   paces.** I move very swiftly. Harold of Norway knows that, and so does
>   Tostig my brother. They lie at ease at Stamford Bridge, and from
>   Stamford Bridge to the Battle Abbey it is--" he muttered over many
>   numbers and forgot  us.

This is from "The Tree of Justice" in "Rewars and Fairies" by Kipling.
http://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/RewardsFaries/treejustice.html

I do not understand the meaning below.
I am glad if somebody kindly teach me.

I have trodden it too often to be out even ten paces.

Comment: "trodden" is the past participle of [*tread*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tread).

Answer (score 2):

"I have trodden it" = "I have walked it."

"Too often" = "too often.

"To be out even ten paces" = "to be mistaken by as many as ten paces."

You understand that this is not modern English of course.